# Unix command to search and replace text recursively

Tags: regex, bash, shell, recursion, sed

I am looking for a UNIX command that helps me to search for a text from all the files in a folder recursively and replace it with new value. After searching in internet I came across this command which worked for me.

> find ./myFolder -type f -print0 | xargs -0 sed -i 's/Application/whatever/g'

Please help me in understanding the above command. I was not able to understand this part of the command : `-print0 | xargs -0`, what this indicates? I know only basics in Unix so finding it difficulty in understanding this. I am using bash shell.

Also are there any alternate commands that provides same functionality in Unix, from google searching I got commands related to `Perl` scripting, I don't know `Perl` so dropped the idea of using it.

Comment: Try saying `man find`, `man xargs`

Comment: The `man` pages are exactly for this: they explain the meaning of the various command line flags, in your current operating system.

Comment: There are many ways to get the same functionality. You can write a script that recursively `cd`s to every directory, `grep`s the files in it, does a shell substitution and writes the result to a tmp file. OR you can use a recursive greo or use find with awk or... The solution you have is probably the best way to do it though.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> `Also are there any alternate commands that provides same functionality in Unix`

Yes you can do all this in find itself:

```
find ./myFolder -type f -exec sed -i 's/Application/whatever/g' '{}' \;
```

`-exec` option in `find` is for:

> `-exec utility [argument ...] ;`
>                True if the program named utility returns a zero value as its exit status.  Optional arguments may be passed to the utility. 
>   The expression must be
>                terminated by a semicolon ('';'').  If you invoke find from a shell you may need to quote the semicolon if the shell would
>   otherwise treat it as a
>                control operator.  If the string ''{}'' appears anywhere in the utility name or the arguments it is replaced by the pathname of
>   the current file.
>                Utility will be executed from the directory from which find was executed.  Utility and arguments are not subject to the
>   further expansion of shell
>                patterns and constructs.

Comment: Thanks Anubhava, why do we need `'{}' \;` in this command? can you please tell me. Also the command in my question uses `-print0` to get the file name, then is that not required in the example you have suggested? Please help me in understanding this.

Comment: Yes `-print0` is not required if using my suggested command with `-exec` option. `{}` is the placeholder for the filename searched by previous `find` command. btw `-print0 prints the pathname of the current file to standard output, followed by an ASCII NUL character` to be piped with `xargs -0`

Answer (score 1):

`find` is passing through all file from a given path
`-type f` limite to file (no folder, ...)
`-print0` give the output to stdout with corresponding file

so this give you all file from a starting point and all subfolder inside

`xargs` allow you to pass parameter to next command coming from previous one (so the file name here)

`sed -i` edit the input (here the passed file)
`'s/Application/whatever/g'` sed command that replace the pattern "Application" by "whatever", on any occurence (`g`)